# What hardware changes will affect WebLogic performance the most?

Tags: performance, hardware, weblogic, redhat

When requesting hardware for a WebLogic server, what hardware would best improve its performance? Should I give it lots of memory, CPU, fast hard drives? The OS is going to be Redhat 4 either Standard or Enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory is cheap. Give it as much as you can. 4 gigs is what, $50?

Comment: Went with memory and that helped a lot. SSD's don't give it much of a boost since there is a lot of caching going on.

Answer (score 1):

That of course depends a lot on what type of applications you run on the server. I know that our WebLogic portal eats quite a lot of memory (10+ gigs) while other apps make due with a lot less.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the applications you deploy on it.  It's impossible to answer, given that we know nothing about the apps deployed, the hardware you have, and the myriad settings available on a typical Java EE app server.

More is always better.  Supply the most memory, the biggest hard drives, the fastest multicore processors you can afford.